# What difference do different tenses make in the meaning?

Tags: tense

1. I was given a different book.
2. I have been given a different book
3. I am given a different book.

This is what I think:- the sentence can be in simple past(1) when one is recounting a past event and that event has nothing to do with the present. Whereas when you use present perfect(2), you mean that there is some relationship of that event(giving of the book) with the present. Although the event happened in the past. And simple present is used when you are narrating a series of events which happened in the past. Simple present can be used in this way when narrating a series of events which have already happened.

Is my explanation regarding what difference using different tenses to talk about the same thing causes to the meaning of the sentence right ?

Comment: The example is wrong but the explanation regarding the usage is right. Right ?

Comment: _And simple present is used when you are narrating a series of events which happened in the past._ No, not usually, though a part of a story describing a character's memories might be written in the present tense. Normally the present is the present - "I am given a different book to review every month".

Comment: You need a better question than "am I right?" for this to be on-topic. Broadly speaking, you're correct about 1 & 2. Example 3 is ungrammatical as written.